# Binding an optional object from one view to be changed in another in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, binding, option-type

I have a top-level object Estate, which is changed throughout the app. And this object has an optional object Meter, which can also be changed by adding Reading. The binding of the Estate is possible with $estate, but it is not so with Optional object. What is the most efficient and error-free way to pass the Meter to another view for changing?

```
import Swiftui

@Binding var estate: Estate
    
    @State var newMeter: Estate.Meter = Estate.Meter()
    @State var isPresentingMeterEditor = false
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            
            List {
                if estate.meters != nil {
                    ForEach(estate.meters!) {meter in 
    //I would like to put here $estate.meters and then $meter to add some new objects to meter in ReadingsList View, but it doesn't work like that.
                        NavigationLink {
                            ReadingList(meter: meter)
                        } label: {
                            Label(meter.name, systemImage: "plus")
                        }
                    } else {}
           }
}
}
```

Comment: Don't make it optional. Just have it be an empty array.

Comment: Just pass the estate and then use its properties

Comment: Since you `... have a top-level object Estate, which is changed throughout the app`, 
have a look at this link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app 
[Managing model data in your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app)